# ComponentDidMount fires twice

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have an issue with navigating between two routes. My scenario is as following:

I have 2 routes: `Route1` and `Route2` - both being siblings to each other.

Let say I am at the Route1, from which I can navigate to Route2 with parameters passed (always). I have investigated buggy behaviour when quickly navigating in the following manner:

`Route1 -> Route2 (param: 1) -> Route 1 -> Route 2 (param: 2)`

I've placed console logs in the `Route2` `componentDidMount` to see what is the output of the following:

```js
const { navigation } = this.props;
console.log(navigation.state.params.param);
```

To my surprise, if I navigate quickly, the output for the scenario above will be:

```
1 
1 
2
```

While the expected behaviour is:

```
1
2
```

Any idea whats going on?

Answer (score 1):

When you navigate from Route2 to Route1, does it come in from the right or left? It's probably getting mounted twice because react-navigation is fun that way :P

You might also be pressing the button too fast. In that case, disable the button for a few hundred ms after the first click.

```js
class Button extends React.Component {
  onPress = () => {
    if (this.props.disabled) return;
    if (this.canPress) {
      this.canPress = false;
      this.props.onPress();
      setTimeout(() => { this.canPress = true; }, this.props.pressTimeout || 500);
    }
  }
....
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using stack navigator then what react-navigation does is for each navigation.navigate it pushes the route in the stack so in your case stack will fill in this way

1. STACK [Route1]
2. STACK [Route2,Route1] . // componentDidMount will be called once printing 1
3. STACK [Route1,Route2,Route1]
4. STACK [Route2, Route1, Route2, Route1] // whereas here componentDidMount will be called once for each pushed routes, printing 1 and 2 for both routes in the stack

So there will be two Route2 in the stack with different params.

That is the way react-navigation.

So instead of using navigate everytime, you can use following options as well according to your needs :

- pop - go back in the stack
- popToTop - go to the top of the stack
- replace - replace the current route with a new one